# How to rotate an existing svg to create three more similar arcs?

Tags: svg

I have created an svg which is an arc which has dotted circles along its path.

Here is my svg file.

[SVG image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqf15.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
   <svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <path d="M52 90 Q 95 35 138 90" fill="transparent"/>
        <!-- Smallest one -->
        <circle cx="53" cy="93" r="2" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="137" cy="93" r="2" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="57" cy="84" r="3" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="133" cy="84" r="3" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="65" cy="75" r="4" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="125" cy="75" r="4" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="77" cy="66" r="5" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="111" cy="66" r="5" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <!-- Center circle -->
        <circle cx="95" cy="62" r="6" fill="#601e1c"/>
    </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Run the code snippet](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G391XA2BH4RQ)

How do I rotate the svg and create a file like this?

[svg expected after rotation along with the original svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtLKA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'n not very sure if this is what you need. Please take a look. I0m putting all your code in a group and I'm reusing it with `<use>` three more times

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
circle{fill:#601e1c}
```

```html
<svg width="190" height="190" viewBox ="0 15 190 190" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="arc">     
        <!-- Smallest one -->
        <circle cx="53" cy="93" r="2"/>
        <circle cx="137" cy="93" r="2"/>

        <circle cx="57" cy="84" r="3"/>
        <circle cx="133" cy="84" r="3"/>

        <circle cx="65" cy="75" r="4"/>
        <circle cx="125" cy="75" r="4"/>

        <circle cx="77" cy="66" r="5" />
        <circle cx="111" cy="66" r="5" />

        <!-- Center circle -->
        <circle cx="95" cy="62" r="6" />
  </g>
  

  <use xlink:href="#arc" transform="rotate(-90,95,110) translate(-5,10)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#arc" transform="rotate(-180,95,110) translate(0,-10)"/>
     <use xlink:href="#arc" transform="rotate(90,95,110) translate(5,10)"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using svg `transform`.

In the snippet below, the rotated arc's circles have been grouped in a `g` element, to which the `rotate` transform has been applied. It is also necessary to use `translate` so that the rotation gets applied based on the center of the arc.

More information can be found in this article: [Transforms on SVG Elements](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/#article-header-id-2).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
   <svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <path d="M52 90 Q 95 35 138 90" fill="transparent"/>
      <!-- original arc -->

        <!-- Smallest one -->
        <circle cx="53" cy="93" r="2" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="137" cy="93" r="2" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="57" cy="84" r="3" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="133" cy="84" r="3" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="65" cy="75" r="4" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="125" cy="75" r="4" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="77" cy="66" r="5" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="111" cy="66" r="5" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <!-- Center circle -->
        <circle cx="95" cy="62" r="6" fill="#601e1c"/>
        
      <!-- rotated arc -->
        <g transform="translate(65,121)rotate(-90)translate(-95,-62)">
        
        <!-- Smallest one -->
        <circle cx="53" cy="93" r="2" fill="#red"/>
        <circle cx="137" cy="93" r="2" fill="#red"/>

        <circle cx="57" cy="84" r="3" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="133" cy="84" r="3" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="65" cy="75" r="4" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="125" cy="75" r="4" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <circle cx="77" cy="66" r="5" fill="#601e1c"/>
        <circle cx="111" cy="66" r="5" fill="#601e1c"/>

        <!-- Center circle -->
        <circle cx="95" cy="62" r="6" fill="#601e1c"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```